# How to automatically update database in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I just downloaded MySQL Workbench 5.2 and really like it. I created a database using New Connection and created my database like normal. I then created an EER Model and used the database. Then i edited some fields in my database (in the non EER model one) but the new data doesn't update in the EER Model. Is there a way that i can automatically update the data from the database in the EER Model without creating a new EER Model every time? Thanks

EDIT:
Also is there a way to create a foreign key outside the EER Model interface. Or does it have to be done ther?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must re-create the ER diagram based on the changes you made to your database. Workbench does not do this automatically (to my knowledge).

You can create foreign key constraints using the `ALTER TABLE` syntax. [See the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> InnoDB enables you to add a new foreign key constraint to a table by using `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
    ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Comment: thanks,  is there a way to create a foreign key outside the EER Model interface. Or does it have to be done there?

Comment: is there a way to do it without syntax?? By clicking on buttons and stuff?

Comment: @NeXtMaN_786 You can do it by changing the table properties. There is a tab for foreign keys/relationships (don't remember exactly). You should really learn how to do it without a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench supports a two-way synchronization. Whenever you have changed something in your model or your database just use Database -> Synchronize Model to open the sync wizard which detects all changes and offers you a detail pane where you can select what to sync in which direction (if the default doesn't fit your needs).

Comment: I wish this was automated, that would be cool. Is there any tool with ER model and automated sync?

Comment: Hello, nice info there!  So we have Forward Engineer to create schema & tables etc from EER model, Reverse Engineer to create EER from existing schema & tables, and Synchronize Model to find and transfer Changes!!! Great Staff, not Automatic but still very helpful!!! THANKS